# An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested class: Facebook - Hav included facebook SDK in application/libraries

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, authentication, oauth

```
public function login(){

$this->load->library('facebook'); // Automatically picks appId and secret from config

$user = $this->facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
            try {
                $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                $user = null;
            }
```

Comment: whether you put facebook.php file in libraries..

Comment: yes... application/libraries/facebook.php .. its here

Comment: do you have base_facebook.php file

Comment: check this link `https://github.com/puneetkay/Facebook-PHP-CodeIgniter` and use the library file in your project.. Then run your code,it will work

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the config.. try this,

```
$fb_config = array(
   'appId'  => 'YOUR APPID',
   'secret' => 'SECRET KEY'
    );
$this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);
```

Comment: nope ! tried this but the same error Unable to load the requested class: Facebook

Comment: @Shashank Bhat whether you put facebook.php file in libraries.

Comment: yes... application/libraries/facebook.php .. its here